# Why is the user redirected to login when already authenticated?

Tags: php, symfony

### Description

I would like to log in with a user when he clicks on the activation link.

In my method `activationAction` of `AuthController`, I do the following:

```
    // we log in the member
    $repo  = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("AppBundle:Members\Members");
    $user = $repo->loadUserByUsername($username);

    //echo dump($user->getRoles());die(); // $user->getRoles() = return array('ROLE_MEMBER');
    if (!$user) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    } else {
        $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, "main", $user->getRoles()); 
        $this->get("security.token_storage")->setToken($token); //now the member is logged in

        $event = new InteractiveLoginEvent($request, $token);
        $this->get("event_dispatcher")->dispatch("security.interactive_login", $event);
    }
```

With this, my user is logged in via my route `/activation`

Then, if i want to change pages and go to `/members/toto` my user is redirected to my login route `/login`

### Question

Why is my user with `ROLE_MEMBER` redirected to the login page when he is already authenticated?

### Additional Information

When I comment the following line `- { path: ^/members/, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }` in my `security.yml` file, I am not redirected anymore.

`security.yml file`:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: true
        provider: our_db_provider

        form_login:
            login_path: login
            check_path: login
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            success_handler: app.security.authentication_handler
            failure_handler: app.security.authentication_handler
        logout:
            path: logout
            target : /

        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path:     /


access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    # when I comment the following line I am not redirected anymore.
    - { path: ^/members/, roles: ROLE_MEMBER }
```

[image]

Comment: are u using JWT token for authentication??
if so are you sure each time your client has JWT token in request header?

Comment: No, i don't use it.
I use only this code.

Comment: Where and how do you define the `$username` variable used in `$repo->loadUserByUsername($username);`?

Comment: Just before : 
$username = $request->query->get('user');

Comment: Are you passing the username as a url parameter for all pages? Like: "example.com/something?user=xyz"? That seems like...  very very very very insecure...

Comment: nope, only on the page /activation?user=toto
sure, it' totally insecure, but, it's a test to understand why my user is logged in on the activation route and not on /members/toto

Comment: Still very insecure. I just need to go to that URL,change the username in the URL to get logged in as any user I want? Either way, you need to store the user in a session or similar. Otherwise your system won't know what, or even if, a user got authenticated in previous requests.

Comment: hum... right, store in session, i will try. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

look for authentication to most used approaches are Session , Token
so you have two option whether set session cookie for user and store user in session
or force user to send token generated in each request

Token approach needs your app client to be in JS
so if your template is generated by php for example if you are using twig as your template engine its better to use session approach.

consider that http is a stateless protocol so when user request to your server for login uri and he/she authenticate successfully everything's not done.

if you are using session php generate a code and set it in users browser so each time client's browser wants to request to your server it sends the cookie (generated code) so you can remember user.

the token approach is very similar but you should implement all parts yourself from generating token to check token existence.

Comment: Interesting philosophical discussion here, but I think you  read the question way too fast. @skyd's problem is a well-known "bug" with the Symfony user provider and token storage. Here's a correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14339837/1724914